# Meu código não reconhece o SCRIPT

Tags: html, jquery, input

Pessoal estou criando uma carteira online para aprender e estou com um problema, queria formatar meu INPUT com uma mascara de Moeda e pelo que vi o JQuery é uma boa opção. Vi um tutorial (no caso esse: http://blog.conradosaud.com.br/artigo/26) porém ele não está funcionando no meu código..

```css
body {

   margin: 0px;
}

#navbar {
 position: absolute;
 top: 165px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 35px;
 background-color: #59b210;
}

#coluna {

 margin-top: 30px;
}

#coluna1 {

 height: auto;
}

#coluna2 {
 
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Menu</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- SCRIPT MASCARA $$ -->
 <script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>           

 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  $('.telefone').mask('(00) 0 0000-0000');
  $('.dinheiro').mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true});
  $('.estado').mask('AA');
        
 </script>


</head>
<body>

 <div id="coluna">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white"><h2>
      <p class="text-center"> NOME </p>
     </div>
     <h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white"><h2>
      <p class="text-center"> NOME  </p>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <h6>
     <p class="text-center"> Gastos Mensais</p>
    </h6>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col">
    <h6>
     <p class="text-center"> Gastos Mensais</p>
    </h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>



<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div id="coluna1" class="col"> 
   
    <p class="text-center">Semana 1 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
    <p class="text-center">Semana 2 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
    <p class="text-center">Semana 3 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
    <p class="text-center">Semana 4 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
    <p class="text-center">Semana 5 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
  </div>
  
  <div id="coluna2" class="col">
    <p class="text-center">Semana 1 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
    <p class="text-center">Semana 2 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
    <p class="text-center">Semana 3 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
    <p class="text-center">Semana 4 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
    <p class="text-center">Semana 5 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boa tarde, olha essa lib aqui eu uso ela e e bem simples de ser usada. https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/#examples segue um exemplo funcional https://gist.github.com/amadeujunior18/d793bb5b3a656c86ca1e3cee43e3bd5e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem problemas com seu código.

1. você está buscando a biblioteca direto do repositório.
2. todos os seus inputs estão com o mesmo `id`.
3. seu código de inicialização estão sendo executados antes da página ser carregada.

O problema de buscar a biblioteca direto do repositório implica que repositório é um ambiente de desenvolvimento onde as possibilidades do autor da biblioteca fazer mudanças no código e esse se tornar incompatível com a sua página ou o autor remover o código serem possibilidades reais. Então para não incorrer nessas possibilidades ou copie o código desejável para o seu servidor e faça a referência a essa cópia ou use de um serviço de entrega de conteúdo `CDN`(Content Delivery Network).
No caso usei um CDN:

```
<script 
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js">
</script>
```

O problema com os `ids` é uma coisa séria. O [atributo global `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) define um identificador que deve ser exclusivo em todo o documento. Seu objetivo é identificar o elemento ao vincular a aplicação de script ou estilização.
Para corrigir o problema removi todos os `ids` e apliquei uma mesmo atributo `class="dinheiro"` a dodos os seus `<inputs>`:

```
<input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
```

Seu código de inicialização estava disparando antes de qualquer conteúdo visual da página ser carregado. Para resolver coloquei o código de inicialização dentro do evento [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) que especifica uma funcionalidade para se executada quando o `DOM` estiver totalmente carregado.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.telefone').mask('(00) 0 0000-0000');
      $('.dinheiro').mask('#.##0,00', {
        reverse: true
      });
      $('.estado').mask('AA');
  });
</script>
```

---

Seu código com os reparos:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #59b210;
}

#coluna {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#coluna1 {
  height: auto;
}

#coluna2 {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- SCRIPT MASCARA $$ -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.telefone').mask('(00) 0 0000-0000');
      $('.dinheiro').mask('#.##0,00', {
        reverse: true
      });
      $('.estado').mask('AA');
    });
  </script>



</head>

<body>

  <div id="coluna">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">
            <h2>
              <p class="text-center"> NOME </p>
          </div>
          <h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">
            <h2>
              <p class="text-center"> NOME </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h6>
            <p class="text-center"> Gastos Mensais</p>
          </h6>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <h6>
            <p class="text-center"> Gastos Mensais</p>
            </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="coluna1" class="col">

          <p class="text-center">Semana 1 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
            <p class="text-center">Semana 2 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
              <p class="text-center">Semana 3 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
                <p class="text-center">Semana 4 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
                  <p class="text-center">Semana 5 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
        </div>

        <div id="coluna2" class="col">
          <p class="text-center">Semana 1 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
            <p class="text-center">Semana 2 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
              <p class="text-center">Semana 3 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
                <p class="text-center">Semana 4 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
                  <p class="text-center">Semana 5 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito Augusto! Muito Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function(){
               $('.telefone').mask('(00) 0 0000-0000');
        $('.dinheiro').mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true});
        $('.estado').mask('AA');
});`

Creio que tenha que fazer o load do jquery

Comment: Mas o script  <script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>     Já não faz o Load?

Answer (score 0):

Configure o JQuery para carregar assim que o documento estiver pronto, como sugeriu o Amadeu Junior:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
               /**
                * $(function()), $(document).ready(function() ou 
                * jQuery(document).ready(), sao usados de maneira 
                * intercambiaveis.
                */
                $(function() {
                        $('.telefone').mask('(00) 0 0000-0000');
                        $('.dinheiro').mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true});
                        $('.estado').mask('AA');
                });

</script>
```

Depois altere os 'inputs', para utilizar o class em vez do id:

```html
<p class="text-center">Semana 1 <label for="dinheiro">R$</label> <input type="text" class="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" style="display:inline-block" /
```

Um identificador único em uma página, como sugere-se, deve ser apenas um na página corrente. Esse identificador segue com a notação #(sustenido/hash) adjunta.

Já, quando se deseja o efeito em mais de um elemento, utilize a marcação . (ponto). Dessa forma, permitindo-se elemento(s) desejado(s) faça(m) parte de uma classe definida.

```html
id="dinheiro"
```

```html
class="dinheiro"
```

Conforme enfatizado, no seu caso, trata-se de uma classe (.dinheiro) que tem efeito em seus N elementos. Portanto, utilize a marcação class="dinheiro", para ter efeitos desejado em todos seus inputs que fazem parte dessa classe, dinheiro.